# Model Agency Database Schema

Tags: database, codeigniter, database-design

I would like to make a model agency based on codeigniter, but im a but stuck with the database, exactly the registration part.

I would like to allow users to sign up as, model, photohgrapher, studo.

I was searchin around the net but couldnt really find anything helpful.

Could someone please give me a hint where i can find a schema for a model agency database? or someghing similar?

I would like to have 3 acount tpye in the registration, models, photographers, studios

And im stuck at this part, so actually the models will have more options like the photographer or the studos, and i dont really want to store all options in one table.

Thank you

Or if someone could give me and opinion would be happy about it.

Comment: not really enough info here to help.  you would have a PERSON or USER type table, and a ACCOUNT_TYPE table...

Comment: You need to use the Party Model, and each party can have different Roles. Read Hay's or Silverston's or Fowler's books on the subject. Safari has two of em for 12 bux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to work with a role based system:

account
id - description - role
0 - Model    - 2
1 - Photographer - 0
2 - Studio  - 1

role
id - add_photos - edit_data - view_model_details
0 - 1 - 0 - 0
1 - 0 - 1 - 1
2 - 1 - 1 - 1

Users
Id - name - account
0 - Norma Jean - 0
1 - Max - 2
2 - James Hickey - 1

The role table lets you define different actions for the groups.

Comment: thanks so much i will red more about this, you where the first who was able to answer my question, thnaks again

Comment: Glad you got it! I was still busy editing the answer because the row names and example content were skewed, but already read it. I'd also like to add that you don't have to re-invent the wheel, CodeIgniter guru Ben Edmunds wrote a really good authentication library for CI: https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth

Answer (score 0):

```
Model
  id  Integer
  name String

Studio
  id Integer
  name String

Registration
  id  Integer
  model_id Integer
  studio_id Integer
  reg_date Date
```